# declaration is incompatible with "__interwork __vfp

Tags: c, compiler-errors, workbench, iar, function-declaration

I'm working with IAR Embedded Workbench, using the C language.

I get the following error:

`Error[Pe147]: declaration is incompatible with "__interwork __vfp void test()" (declared at line 1 of "C:\test_Project\test\EWARM/../Inc\test.h") C:\test_Project\test\Src\test.c 3`

**Contents of test.h**:

```c
void test();
```

**Contents of test.c**:

```c
#include "test.h"

void test(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, float *data, uint16_t send_size)
{
    //omission
}
```

If I delete the argument `uint16_t send_size` of the test function, the compilation succeeds.

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that there is a discrepancy between the way test() was declared in test.h and the way it was implemented in test.c. Your function parameters must match.

In test.h, instead of

```
void test();
```

use

```
void test(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, float *data, uint16_t send_size);
```

Comment: Do you by any change also know what the "__interwork_vfp" part of the error means? And why this error does not occur with the (just as wrong) function `void test(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, float *data)`? This seems to only partially answer the question. (Still a useful hint though!)